# Use JQuery from Webjars using RequireJS

Tags: jquery, maven, requirejs, webjars

I'm trying to include `JQuery` in a web app built with `maven`, using `RequireJS` to define `Javascript` modules.

I followed `RequireJS` documentation [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html), which explains how to do to use `JQuery` with `RequireJS`. I have in addition a `maven` build.

Here's what I did:

My main.js, called by the data-main of `RequireJS` in my `HTML`

```
define(function() {
// Configuration of RequireJS
    requirejs.config({
        // No module can start with require. This can potentially allow easier definition of some elements
        enforceDefine : true,

        map : {
            '*': { 
                'jquery': 'libs/jquery',
            },

            // To make jquery work with requireJS: see http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html
            // 'jquery' wants the real jQuery module
            // though. If this line was not here, there would
            // be an unresolvable cyclic dependency.
            'libs/jquery': { 'jquery': 'jquery' },
        },

        // The base URL is just the top-level directory where the files are stored
        baseUrl : './',

        // Kick-start the application by loading these files
        deps : [ 'MyMainPanel' ],
    });
});
```

I defined a "custom" JQuery (as in RequireJS documentation), lying in /libs/jquery.js

```
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

And in my `maven` `pom.xml`:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>${jquery.version}</version>
</dependency>
...
```

At the instanciation of a module using jquery, I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

The module using JQuery is the following one:

```
define(['ractive',
        'jquery',
        function(Ractive,
                $,
){
    var Panel  = Ractive.extend({
        el:"mainPanel",

        oninit: function(){
            $.ajax({url: "/myURL"}).done(function(types){
                // Work
            })
        }
    })

    return Panel
})
```

Comment: What web framework are you using and how are you exposing the WebJars via a URL?

Comment: I use Spring-boot and a few other webjars (RactiveJS for example). RactiveJS works fine with RequireJS, not JQuery

Comment: Try a config like: https://github.com/webjars/jquery/blob/master/pom.xml#L49-L54

Comment: The result is : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined` in my custom requireJs

Comment: Not sure what to do about that one.  Sorry.

Comment: Looks like setting enforceDefine to false fixed the issue. I don't know why, but this works. I'll try to investigate to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found (which is a workaround) is playing woth "enforceDefine" value:

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine : false,

    map : {
        'libs/jquery' : {
            'jquery' : "webjars/jquery/${jquery.version}/jquery"
        },

        '*': { 
            'jquery' : 'libs/jquery', 
        },
    },

    baseUrl : './',

    deps : [ 'MyMainPanel' ],
});
```

I don't know why it works, but it works. I'll keep it so until I find a better solution.